Denying access to users on an ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint
I have an endpoint in my API like: api/users/{:userId}/...
I only want the user with userId to have access to his own endpoint and not to the endpoints of any other user.
I implemented a JWT Bearer token, which is used for authorization. I get the id from it and check if it matches the route the user wants to access:
[HttpGet("{userId:int}"), Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserById([FromRoute] int userId)
{
    var id = int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

    if (id != userId)
    {
        return BadRequest("Access denied.");
    }
    
    var user = await unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
    
    if (user == null)  
        return NotFound("User not found");

    return Ok(user);
}

Now, I don't think this is the correct approach. The token can easily be tampered with and the id changed. How else could I do this?

"I implemented a JWT Bearer token" ...  "The token can easily be tampered" is your JWT signed?

@gunr2171 Yes it is signed. You are right. It shouldn't be a problem then. Changing the payload to another user-id shouldn't be possible. Still a question regardless, are there other/better ways to implement this behaviour? An attack vector could still happen if the key is leaked.

I would recommend using Forbidden (HTTP 403) when trying to signal someone (even if authenticated) isn't allowed to call a certain function. "Bad request" is a bit of an overly generic HTTP status code....

"An attack vector could still happen if the key is leaked" what "key" do you mean? The JWT itself? A JWT is a bearer token - anyone with the key is allowed in. That's why bearer tokens have short expirations, something around 15 minutes. But the receiver of the JWT is responsible for keeping that information safe.

In the past I have specifically written integration tests which prove that a tampered token is rejected - generate a valid JWT, parse it, replace one of the claims, re-encode it and call the API and you should get a 403 and the application telemetry should record that it saw a bad token signature.

@TomW Yes, I get a 403. I tried to temper with the token, but my backend didn't accept it. Should write a tests for it, indeed.

@gunr2171 I meant the key used to sign the tokens on the backend. Apologies for not clarifying. Should the application change up the token key used to sign the signature on a regular interval (i.e. monthly)? From what I understand there is a long-lived token that is used to refresh the short-lived token. Still looking into it though.
